# Using grep/awk to extract info from a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file named `info.txt` that contains information like this:

```
=== Some Unique Headline ===
Version: 1.2.0

== Changelog ==

= 1.2.0 =
* Mac release
* Security fix

= 1.0.0 =
* Windows release
```

I want to extract 2 sections.

1. the `Version` number, `1.2.0` I can use this:

```
grep 'Version:' info.txt | cut -d\   -f3
```

2. I want to extract the info under the changelog heading that matches that version. For example, since the `Version` is 1.2.0 the following text will be extracted (text under heading 1.2.0 in the changelog):

```
* Mac release
* Security fix
```

Is there a way to do this with `grep` or `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a simple state machine in awk to select the relevant lines:

```
        /^=== /        { s = 3; next }
s==3 && $1=="Version:" { v = $2 }
        /^== /         { s = 2; d = ($2=="Changelog") }
   d && /^= /          { s = 1; p = ($2==v); next }
   p && $0             { print }
```

- `s` stores a state:

  - `s==3` : section
  - `s==2` : subsection
  - `s==1` : subsubsection (not really needed)
- `d` stores another state - nonzero when in changelog subsection
- `p` stores another state - nonzero when printable line
- `v` holds the version once found
- `p && $0` : output non-empty printable lines

Store in a file (say "script") and invoke as `awk -f script info.txt`

Comment: I get this error `awk: illegal statement at source line 2 source file script` also `Version` wont always be the second line, there are other info before and after that

Comment: my code doesn't care where the version line is except that it is inside the details section

Comment: thank you, this code works great, I just noticed I made some mistakes in the initial question, the first heading should be `===` but I dont know how to update this code to reflect that. And also can it ignore the title inside it as I want to make this as generic as possible to use for multiple files?

Comment: Thank you for the update, if I add another section below or above changelog , for example `== License ==` then this no longer works, is it possible to look based on the section `Changelog` and not the position of it?

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS="" '
/Version:/{
  ver=$NF
  print $NF
  next
}
/Changelog/{
  found1=1
  next
}
found1 && $0 ~ ver{
  sub(/^[^\n]*\n*/,"")
  print
  found1=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: thanks, this doesnt seem to output the content of changelog, I get two `1.2.0`

Comment: @RainMan, this is a working code, I have tested it with your shown samples. Could you please confirm that your actual file is same as shown samples? OR its different?

Comment: I tested it using the above example, you are able to output `* Mac release
* Security fix`?

Comment: @RainMan, I have edited the code, could you please do check it once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: thank you, but this also outputs the version number `1.2.0` which is not desired. thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a example without grep and awk.
There is a way to use regex matching in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ ^Version:\ (.+)$ ]]; then
    ver=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  elif [[ $line =~ ^=\ ([0-9\.]+)\ = ]]; then
    cur=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  elif [[ "$cur" != "" && "$ver" = "$cur" ]]; then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < info.txt
```

Comment: thank you but I get an empty result when I do `bash info.sh` - the output is empty

Comment: Avoiding awk for text processing is like avoiding a hammer for driving nails or a screwdriver for screws - it's the tool that the guys who invented shell invented for shell to call for this specific task. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` in paragraph mode:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' -v OFS='\n' '/Version/ {split($0,a,/:/);vn = a[2]} $1 ~ vn {print $2,$3}' file
* Mac release
* Security fix
```

more readable:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' -v OFS='\n' '
        /Version/ {split($0,a,/:/);vn = a[2]} 
        $1 ~ vn {print $2,$3}
' file
* Mac release
* Security fix
```

- `vn` the version number. You can get it using the `split()` function.
- If the line contain `vn` then print from that parapraph only $2 and $3: `$1 ~ vn {print $2,$3}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the version, maybe using `f2` instead of `f3` in your question's command
ver=`grep 'Version:' info.txt | cut -d\  -f2`

# get the heading that matches that version
ver_line=`grep -v 'Version:' info.txt |grep "$ver"`

# grep the hole file by `-z` which treat all lines as one big line
# and format the output to remove the can visibility character
grep -Pzo '(?<='"$ver_line"')[^=]*(?==)' info.txt | cat -v | grep -Ev "^$|^\^"
```

- `grep` OPTIONS quote:

> -P, --perl-regexp
> Interpret  the  pattern  as  a  Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).

> -z, --null-data
> Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.   Like  the  -Z  or  --null
> option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

You could get this, because of the `-z` option will bring `the ASCII NUL character` at the end.

```
# grep -Pzo '(?<='"$ver_line"')[^=]*(?==)' info.txt | cat -v

* Mac release
* Security fix

^@
```

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of backticks for command substitution, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you asked for would be:

```
$ awk '$1=="Version:"{ver="= "$2" ="} !NF{f=0} f; $0==ver{f=1}' file
* Mac release
* Security fix
```

but since the current version will be the first changelog you don't need to read that version number first, all you really need is:

```
$ awk '$1=="*"{f=1} f&&!NF{exit} f' file
* Mac release
* Security fix
```